# Qualtrics: using space bar to continue, study autoadvancing on next item if item left unanswered before space bar press

Tags: javascript, keycode, qualtrics

I'm very new to JavaScript, and I'm currently trying to add a custom code to my Qualtrics survey that makes it so pressing the spacebar continues the survey in the "Text/Graphic" question type. I have a code that should be working; however, I'm getting an "Unexpected token (" error.

Here is the code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {

        function(){
            that.clickNextButton();
        }

}
}

});`
```

I also found this answer to a similar question from a couple of years back:

Here is a simplified version that works (updated to hide NextButton):

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()  {
$('NextButton').hide();         
document.on("keydown", function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode === 13) $('NextButton').click();
});
});
```

This code, however, doesn't work at all in my survey (as if it wasn't even there).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

____ Edit _____

The code I have now used is the following:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
    $('NextButton').hide();
    document.on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) $('NextButton').click();
    });
});

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/

});
```

The problem I have now is that the study autoadvances the next question whenever I press spacebar before ansewring a previous question.

**Example**
Question 1: Is the sentence you just saw a sensible continuation for the preceding sentence?
 * participant presses space bar before answering the question with F for no and J for yes
 * The study reminds the participant that they need to answer the question before proceeding to the next question
* Participant answers the question and the study automatically proceeds to the next question, because answering validates the question
--> the study only lets the participant see the next item for a second, and then autoadvances to the next item without the participant pressing any key.

The code I use for the F + J keys is the following:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
    {

this.hideNextButton();
this.hidePreviousButton();
var that = this;
Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
  var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 74: // 'f'  was pressed
      choiceID = 2;
      break;
    case 70: // 'j' was pressed
      choiceID = 1;
      break;
  }

  if (choiceID) {
    Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
    that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    that.clickNextButton();
    }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't work due to a timing issue. Use addOnReady instead:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
    $('NextButton').hide();
    document.on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) $('NextButton').click();
    });
});
```

Note: with split screen preview mode you have to click in the window first or it won't recognize the key press.

**EDIT:**

I couldn't recreate your problem (your code worked as is for me when I tried it).  However, try the following.  It is cleaner and consistent. If it works be sure to accept the answer.

Space bar question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
    $('NextButton').hide();
    if($('PreviousButton')) $('PreviousButton').hide();
    var evt = document.on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {  //space bar pressed
            evt.stop();
            $('NextButton').click();
        }   
    });
});
```

Yes/No question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
    $('NextButton').hide();
    if($('PreviousButton')) $('PreviousButton').hide();
    var that = this;
    var evt = document.on('keydown', function(e) {
        var choiceID = null;
        if(e.which == 70) choiceID = 1;     //'f' was pressed
        else if(e.which == 74) choiceID = 2;    //'j' was pressed

        if (choiceID) {
            evt.stop();
            that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
            $('NextButton').click();
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It does work now but I've still got a slight problem. I have items in my study in which the participant needs to answer a yes-no question with key strokes, namely F for no and J for yes. I added the code for the continuation by space bar at the beginning of the study, on the very first page, and it works fine on the whole study except for these yes-no questions. I don't want the participants to be able to continue the survey before answering the question, and so the survey shows a "please answer this question first"-message if they press space bar before...

Comment: ... answering the question. However, once I have pressed space bar to continue the study and was then "forced" to answer the question by pressing F or J, the study autoadvances the next question! I think it must be recording the space bar press before answering the question, and so it's as if I had pressed "continue" on the next item. How could I fix this? My code for the F / J keys:

Comment: {

this.hideNextButton();
this.hidePreviousButton();
var that = this;
Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
  var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 74: // 'f'  was pressed
      choiceID = 2;
      break;
    case 70: // 'j' was pressed
      choiceID = 1;
      break;
  }

  if (choiceID) {
    Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
    that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    that.clickNextButton();
 } 
 });
});

Comment: Is the JavaScript code for the space bar handler in the in the header/footer of the survey?  It would be easier to look at if you updated your post to include the new code.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! 
So I have made 4 blocks which will be randomly distributed to the participants, and the code for the space bar is attached to the first question, which is just the introduction text to the survey. I will update the post to include the code.

Comment: The edited version works perfectly, thank you SO much T. Gibbons! You totally saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `function()` around `that.clicknextbutton()`, and change `that` to `this`. `that` doesn't make sense unless it is a variable set to the `this` keyword. The `function(){}` syntax is used to define an expression in a parameter.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
                this.clickNextButton();    
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! 
Seems better already, but I'm now getting another error: Unexpected token }. :(

Comment: I had improper syntax. I edited to make it work now. I missed the `);` on the ending of the event listener.